# How to create public facing pages in salesforce

Tags: visualforce, force.com, community

I have a requirement where i need to display the information and that should visible to all.

Please let me know how could i achieve this..

Comment: Welcome to salesforce.stackexchange Karan. Have you already looked at the site.com or communities documentation. While we're here to help, we do expect you to at least do some research or indicate why you're unable to find a solution.

Answer (score 3):

You could use Force.com sites https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Sites which is meant for exposing Salesforce  data publicly.